# How to get thirrd party oAuth v2 token From UI using msal-angular

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

Consider this scenario:
I have an application which is registered in Azure AD and under that in API permissions one API is configured. I want to call that API but it is not deployed in our namespace and is a separate application. So I need to fetch the the API token first and then call the API. How can I achieve this result. The API team is asking to call the OAuth API with client key and secret key but this will increase security risk of leaking secret key

I tried using the `protectedResourceMap` to use the new scope but that didn't worked as I guess the Application is not registered under my Azure AD application.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to fetch the API token first and then call the API. How can I achieve this result.

To fetch the access token for an API, you have to create an **Azure AD Application and Expose an API** like below:

[image]

And **add the API permissions** like below:

[image]

Now, I generated **auth-code** using below authorize endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms 
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://APIAppClientID/access_as_user
&state=12345
```

[image]

I generated **access token** via Postman by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:api://APIAppClientID/access_as_user
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

The **access token got generated for the API** like below:

[image]

*By using the above access token, you can now call the API.*

To get the access token using **`@azure/msal-angular`**, make use of below code refer this [**Blog**](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/msal-angular/).

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MsalModule.forRoot({
            auth: {
                clientId: "Your client ID"
            }
        }, {
            protectedResourceMap: [
                               ['https://api.myapplication.com/users/*', ['access_as_user']]
            ]
        })
    ],
    providers: [
        ProductService, 
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: MsalInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Reference:**

[microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/lib/msal-angular AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js · GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular#3-get-tokens-for-web-api-calls) by tnorling